# AWS lambda works but not Gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

On the beginning I would like to mention that I just start learning AWS tools.

I have two request handlers created with Java. Both of them have the same `handleRequest` method which looks like one below

```java
public class SecondHandler implements RequestHandler<JSONObject, List<Candidate>> {
 

    @Override
    public List<Object> handleRequest(JSONObject request, Context context) {
        List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(request + " <<");
         String isActive = String.valueOf(request.getString("isActive"));        
        
        if(!isActive) return objectList;

        for(Object obj : objectList) {
          // here will go logic
        }

      
        return objectList;
    }
}
```

First method is used to return some list of object without sending any arguments to it. And it work fine when calling it with AWS lambda, and when using AWS Gateways.

Second method I am trying to call with sending JSONObject with one filed like

```json
{
  "isActive" : "yes"
}
```

But when I do the test I am getting error `"JSONObject[\"isActive\"] not found."`. And I am sure that this is related to my `JSONObject request` argument, because when I am changing its type to `Map<String, String>` it works fine, I am getting what I want when using AWS Lambda. But with `Map` in place when I try to call this with AWS Gateway I am getting

```json
{ "message" : "Internal server error" }
```

When checking the logs I can see there is problem with parsing. So basically AWS Gateway can not parse `Map<String, String>`.

Could someone tell me, what I do not understand about lambda and gateways? Why those tools have such problem with parsing simple JSON? What I should do?

PS. I also had the issue with parsing on the first method, when using `Map<String, String>` that is why I decided to use `JSONObject`, and that solved the issue for first method.

Comment: Are you using proxy integration or non-proxy integration?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary non-proxy

Comment: What is your method request payload specified? Have you specified anything?

Comment: I do not specified request. I am sending simple json object.

Comment: Can you please post your entire `Handler`? Does it implement any interfaces?

Comment: it implements `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler`.

Comment: What does it say in CloudWatch? We need the full handler code - the above won't reproduce your problem right now. How are you trying to access `request`? Where do you get the `"JSONObject[\"isActive\"] not found."` error?

Comment: Right now you have my entire handler. I just try it to recreate step by step. The when I upload this code into lambda and try call it with `Test` button and simple json `{ "isActive" : "yes" }` I am getting that error. In my `System.out.println` I can see the `request` object is empty

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `Map<String, Object>`, implement the `RequestStreamHandler` interface.

It doesn't require a data type and will provide you with an `InputStream`. You can then convert the stream to any compatible data type, including a `JSONObject`.

Try this:

```
public class SecondHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        JsonElement eventElement = new JsonParser().parse(reader);
        JsonObject event = (JsonObject) eventElement;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ermiya Eskandary for help. You help figured out that my handler should look like one below.

```java
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class SecondHandler {

  public void handleRequest(InputStream input, Context context) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(input));
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(bufferedReader);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tokener);

    // and in here I can use my json 
  }
}
```

I was trying use your method, but `new JsonPArser().parse(reader);` not sure what library you were using there. I failed twice with Gson and Jackson. But your suggestion help to come up with proper solution.  thanks again.